# Help with Memory leak: init NSMutableArray from file

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

In some point in my app, I need to load a list from a file, so I implement this method to load the list:

```
-(void)loadList
{
    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];  //This is a method return the path of file
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        self.list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:tempArray];
        [tempArray release];
    }
}
```

The self.list is a (retain) property.

I think the leak is from [alloc] when I init the selfl.list. I used

```
self.list = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:tempArray]autorelease];
```

But the app crashes due to EXC_BAD_ACCESS. So I am confused here how to solve this.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: try this code `self.list = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];`

Answer (score 3):

Just assign,

```
self.list = tempArray;
```

As *tempArray* is already an array, you don't have to create another array from it. You ca directly assign to *self.list*.

Answer (score 1):

```
  There is no need to allocate another time for array .So just assign directly

    -(void)loadList
   {
NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];  //This is a method return the path of file
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    self.list = [tempArray copy];
    [tempArray release];
}
 }
```

Comment: your are doing build and analyze ?

Answer (score 0):

is your list property assign or retain?
if it is retain, then you should change this:

```
self.list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:tempArray];
```

to this:

```
self.list = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't **autorelease** it. (I guess).